# Wordpress child theme - Remove main theme Javascript file

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

In main theme `functions.php` I have :

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'template', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/template.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
```

In child theme `functions.php` I've added :

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_main_script' );
    function remove_main_script()
    {
        wp_dequeue_script('template');
    }
```

The file `template.js` is still loaded. How can I remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a priority to `add_action()` (`10` is the default), to ensure that the parent styles and scripts are registered before you deregister them via your child theme:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_main_script', 20 );
function remove_main_script()
{
    wp_dequeue_script('template');
}
```

Comment: Just by curiosity, It's 10 or 1 based scale?  Ex: can we use 11 or 12 for priority?

Comment: @NaourassDerouichi , good question. You can use any positive `integer` for the priority (`11` would be fine).